# Implementing Content-Security-Policy with google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, blazor-server-side, content-security-policy

I've been asked to implmenet a content security policy on one of our Blazor web applications which is public facing.

If I add this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' *.jquery.com *.js.stripe.com *.cloudflare.com www.googletagmanager.com res.cloudinary.com *.gtm.js; upgrade-insecure-requests;">
```

Everything is able to source load perfectly fine apart from the google tag manager stuff, I get these console errors:

[image]

Obviously if I use 'unsafe-inline' within the policy this will allow the `gtm.js` files to load, however it also renders the CSP largely pointless.

Couple of questions.

1. Why is GTM still unable to load even though I have effectively
   whitelisted gtm.
2. If using a nonce or hash is the only legitimate way around
   this, how do I setup a nonce value in the _host file of a Blazor
   server web application, everyone talks this approach up but i cannot for the life of me fine an example to follow.

Comment: It looks like GTM is loading ok, it would just be the scripts it embeds into the page which are not. We have used a nonce since you can pass it to GTM and it will add it to any scripts that it adds so you don't need to update the CSP each time you add a new one but sorry, never done it in Blazor, in dotnet core you can add a package like https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore-security-headers

Comment: all the CSP configuration goes into the _Host file in Blazor, which is effecively just a cshtml page, I can run JS in there, and decorate all my <script> tags with an additional nonce value, i just dont understand how to generate a unique nonce in there using javascript. Ive got the GTM nonce version of the javascript that is required, would just love to see a proper implementation example of this

Answer (score 0):

Google has a quite comprehensive article on how to implement tag maanger with a CSP: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/csp

When you set up a nonce, all the GTM scripts will also have this nonce. You should generate a nonce on each pageload and make sure that it is set both in your CSP and set as described in the article above.

Comment: I will make this as the answer if you are able to contain a code example of generating the nonce in the _Host.cshtml file within a Blazor application as per the question, as this has been my main issue